# Set all the possible variables in range Python

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

I one to try to create a big loop to try two variables in one time for each loop with `-1<=a<=1` and `-1<=b<=1`  with an increment of `0.0001` in my function.

**Question**

> I can get different results coming from the `a` and `b` variables.

Comment: `for i in range(-1, 1.0001, 0.0001):`

Comment: Yes but this will always put my a and b variables in the same values, I also want when they are different lets say when a=0.5 and b will be equals =-0.3 for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a nested loop

```
import numpy as np
for a in np.arange(-1, 1.0001, 0.0001):
    for b in np.arange(-1, 1.0001, 0.0001):
        print(a + b)
```

If you don't need/want numpy

```
for a in range(-1000, 1001):
    for b in range(-1000, 1001):
        print(a/1000 + b/1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the possible combinations, as understood from your comment, do:

```
for a in np.arange(-1, 1.0001, 0.0001):
    for b in np.arange(-1, 1.0001, 0.0001):
```

Comment: range only works for integers, what is needed is `np.arange`

Comment: @SayandipDutta My bad. Fixed it now, tnx :)

Comment: thank you this works, will this make my loop slow ?

Comment: @Gogo78 depends on what you are doing inside, but yes, if you want to get 20,000 * 20,000 = 400,000,000 combinations of 2 functions, that's a lot of work...

Comment: Try to play with iterator objects from some `itertool` functions. Something like `product` or `combination` and then `zip` the `range`s together and loop in one go, that way you avoid nesting, should make the program faster.